# Scala adding item to seq results in type Equals

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm trying to understand the behavior of this code:

[image]

```
  def getListsByLC(lcId: Int): Action[AnyContent] = Action.async {
    listRepo.getListsByLC(lcId).flatMap { lists =>
      val newLists: Seq[Future[Seq[List]]] = lists.map { list =>
        itemRepo.getItemsByList(list.id).map { items =>
          list.items.get :+ items
        }
      }


      Future.sequence(newLists).map(_.flatten).map { lists =>
        Ok(Json.obj("lists" -> lists))
      }
    }
  }
```

I have `seq` of lists and within `List` there's another `seq` of `Item`. I want to add those `items` to each corresponding `list`. My compiler somehow tells me that the return of `lists.map { ... }` is a `Equals`. I can't find any documentation on this behavior. What am I doing wrong? Am I missing something? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please copy paste the code into the question.

Comment: `Equals` is the trait shared by `list.items.get` and `items` and is the only thing that the Scala type checker can find in common between those two; this is an indication the types of those two things are not what you expect.

You've got another weird thing; `Seq[Future[Seq[List]]]` is a weird type signature unless you've defined a custom class called `List`. A `Seq[List]` is a sequence of the `List` companion object again and again, not a `Seq` of lists of something. Lists are higher-kinded types, i.e. they take a type argument to become an actual concrete type (e.g. `List[Int]`).

Comment: @badcook `Seq[List]` might be confusing. Yes, I defined a custom class called `List`. Thanks for your comment, I will try to fix the `Equals` situation :)

Answer (score 1):

`Equals` is a Scala trait defined as "a trait containing operations for equality". This is unexpected behavior in your code. This probably means that your code is not returning the expected return type. I strongly suspect it's to do with the `:+` function.

Read more about list concatenation here: https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-merge-scala-lists-concatenate